# Cascading promises in parallel

Tags: promise, es6-promise

I have 2 threads running in parallel (A, B) with 2 functions running in sequence in each case.
For this, I want to use promises and I thought about something like:
A: a1().then(a2());
B: b1().then(b2());

The code is:

```
console.log("Building A1");

const a1Promise = () => { return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  console.log("A1 Started");
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("A1 completed");
    resolve();
  }, 1000);
}) };

console.log("Building B1");

const b1Promise = () => { return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  console.log("B1 Started");
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("B1 completed");
    resolve();
  }, 1500);
}) };

console.log("Building A2");

const a2Promise = () => { a1Promise().then(() => {
   new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log("A2 Started");
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("A2 completed");
      resolve();
    }, 2000);
  });
}) };

console.log("Building B2");

const b2Promise = () => { b1Promise().then(() => {
   new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log("B2 Started");
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("B2 completed");
      resolve();
    }, 2500);
  });
}) };

console.log("Before Promise All");

Promise.all([a2Promise(), b2Promise()]).then(() => {
  console.log("All 'A' and 'B' promises completed in parallel"); });
```

And the output in the console is:

Building A1
Building B1
Building A2
Building B2
Before Promise All
A1 Started
B1 Started
All 'A' and 'B' promises completed in parallel
A1 completed
A2 Started
B1 completed
B2 Started
A2 completed
B2 completed

I would have expected the message "All 'A' and 'B' pro..." to be shown at the end.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You forgot to `return` from `a2Promise` and from the `then` handler inside (and the same in `b2Promise`)

Comment: Equivalently, if you were to remove the brackets and semicolons such that `() => { return new Promise(...); }` becomes `() => new Promise(...)`, this would work as well. I imagine this error might have come from exactly that syntax migration or its reverse, half-complete.